# Implementing the Newton -Raphson method for finding the zeros of a function

Tags: numerics, core-language

```
f[x_] = x - 0.8 - 0.2 (sinx)

x0 = Pi;    
n = 20;

NewtonsMethodList[f, {x_, Pi}, 20] := 
  NestList[# - Function[x, f][#]/Derivative[1][Function[x, f]][#] &, Pi, 20]
```

I want to apply the newton raphson method to $x - 0.8 -0.2 \sin x$ and have little experience with *Mathematica*, but am told this is an efficient and useful tool to find a root. Based on the information in MathWorld, I tried this out, and a number of combinations, but do not understand how to get the series of values I would expect.

Comment: An important thing to note, as demonstrated by @RunnyKine, is that built-in functions start with a capital letter, and are applied to their arguments with [square brackets].  So `(sinx)` as you have written it should be `Sin[x]`.  The parens are unnecessary in this case, too.

Comment: Excellent! I got it working in a more concise and straightforward method after rewriting it.

Answer (score 11):

Note that `sin` is not a function in *Mathematica*, instead use `Sin` with a capital `S` and functions use square brackets to hold their arguments. So `Sin[x]` instead of `sin(x)` or even `sinx` as you have it.
You can use `NestWhile` or `NestWhileList` (for the list of values) also for this problem:

```
f[x_] := x - 0.8 - 0.2 Sin[x]   

newtonsMethod[foo_, k_, s_: 0.0001] := NestWhile[# - foo[#]/foo'[#] &, k, Abs[foo @ #] > s &]
```

Use:

```
newtonsMethod[f, 1]
```

> 0.964333889

Since you already used `NestList`, you can also use `Nest` (just for the final value) as follows:

```
Nest[N[# - f[#] / f'[#]] &, Pi, 20]
```

> 0.964333888

Compare with `FindRoot`

```
FindRoot[f[x], {x, Pi}]
```

> {x -> 0.964333888}

If you are coming from other procedural languages the following `Do` loop versions may help you understand what's happening:

```
x1 = Pi;
Do[x1 = N[x1 - f[x1]/f'[x1]], {20}]
```

Now evaluating `x1` we get

```
x1
```

> 0.964333888

You can use `Reap` and `Sow` to collect the values in this approach:

```
x1 = Pi;
res = Last @ Reap[Do[Sow[x1 = N[x1 - f[x1] / f'[x1]]], {20}]]
```

> ```
> {{1.19026544, 0.969277975, 0.964336158, 0.964333888, 0.964333888, 
>   0.964333888, 0.964333888, 0.964333888, 0.964333888, 0.964333888, 
>   0.964333888, 0.964333888, 0.964333888, 0.964333888, 0.964333888, 
>   0.964333888, 0.964333888, 0.964333888, 0.964333888, 0.964333888}}
> ```

Which you can plot if desired:

```
ListPlot[res]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

```
fun = x - 0.8 - 0.2 Sin[x]

newton1[fun_, n_] := 
 With[{f = fun/D[fun, x]}, Nest[# - f /. x -> # &, 2., n]]

newton1[fun, 10]
```

> 0.964334

```
newton2[fun_, n_] :=
 With[{f = fun/D[fun, x]}, NestList[# - f /. x -> # &, 2., n]]

ListLinePlot[newton2[fun, 10],
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 Mesh -> All,
 MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], Red],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
f = # / D[#, x] & [fun]
```

[image]

```
FixedPoint[# - f /. x -> # &, 2.]
```

> 0.964334

Comment: Nice graph. +1.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the convergents, I recommend[`FixedPointList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FixedPointList.html).

```
f[x_] := x - 0.8 - 0.2 Sin[x]
newtonsMethodList[f_, x0_, n_] := 
  With[{iter = # - f[#]/D[f[#], #]}, FixedPointList[iter &, x0, n]]
newtonsMethodList[f, N @ Pi, 10]
```

> ```
> {3.14159, 1.19027, 0.969278, 0.964336, 0.964334, 0.964334, 0.964334}
> ```

Notice that, although I set a limit of ten iterations, the method obtained convergence in six.

If you just want the answer, substitute `FixedPoint` for `FixedPointList`.

```
newtonsMethod[f_, x0_, n_] := 
  With[{iter = # - f[#]/D[f[#], #]}, FixedPoint[iter &, x0, n]]
x= newtonsMethod[f, N @ Pi, 10]
```

> ```
> 0.964334
> ```

It's a good idea to always check the results.

```
f[x]
```

> ```
> -2.77556*10^-17
> ```

Answer (score 2):

To get the list  that you want

```
f[x_] = x - .8 - .2* Sin[x] // Simplify;

NewtonsMethodList[f_, x0_, n : _Integer : 20] := 
 NestList[# - f[#]/f'[#] &, x0, n]

(nml1 = NewtonsMethodList[f, Pi // N]) // InputForm
```

> {3.141592653589793, 
>    1.1902654422649652, 
>    0.9692779750858744, 
>    0.9643361576782574, 
>    0.9643338876957006, 
>    0.9643338876952227, 
>    0.9643338876952227, 
>    0.9643338876952227, 
>    0.9643338876952227, 
>    0.9643338876952227, 
>    0.9643338876952227, 
>    0.9643338876952227, 
>    0.9643338876952227, 
>    0.9643338876952227, 
>    0.9643338876952227, 
>    0.9643338876952227, 
>    0.9643338876952227, 
>    0.9643338876952227, 
>    0.9643338876952227, 
>    0.9643338876952227, 
>    0.9643338876952227}

Note that the list continues past the point where the value stops changing. This can be avoided by using either NestWhileList or FixedPointList.

```
NewtonsMethodList2[f_, x0_, test_: UnsameQ] := 
 NestWhileList[# - f[#]/f'[#] &, x0, test, 2]

(nml2 = NewtonsMethodList2[f, Pi // N]) // InputForm
```

> {3.141592653589793, 
>   1.1902654422649652, 
>   0.9692779750858744, 
>   0.9643361576782574, 
>   0.9643338876957006, 
>   0.9643338876952227, 
>   0.9643338876952227}

```
nml2 == Take[nml1, Length[nml2]]
```

> True

```
NewtonsMethodList3[f_, x0_] := FixedPointList[# - f[#]/f'[#] &, x0]

(nml3 = NewtonsMethodList3[f, Pi // N]) // InputForm
```

> {3.141592653589793, 
>    1.1902654422649652, 
>    0.9692779750858744, 
>    0.9643361576782574, 
>    0.9643338876957006, 
>    0.9643338876952227, 
>    0.9643338876952227}

```
nml2 == nml3
```

> True